# Form methods with nested array issue

Tags: php, laravel, twig

When I use nested arrays in methods in my view I get undefined offset error:
*An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Undefined offset: 0") in "admin.edition.form" at line 16.*

I use this conforming to the Laravel Form Builder doc, doesn't work:

```
{{ form_model(edition,{'method' : 'PUT', 'class' : 'form-horizontal', 'role' : 'form', 'route' : {'edition.update' : edition.id} })|raw }}
```

This work without the nested array:

```
{{ form_model(edition,{'method' : 'PUT', 'class' : 'form-horizontal', 'role' : 'form' })|raw }}
```

Ty, lory.

Comment: Your code looks like you're trying to pass a JavaScript object (JSON) to the `form_model` method. Shouldn't that be `array('method' => 'PUT', ...)` or `['method' => 'PUT', ...]`. That said, I didn't even know the form_model helper function existed.

Comment: No I'm using twig instead of blade template engine

Comment: cf array syntax in twig: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#literals

Comment: Ahh sorry. My bad. In that case, try the newsted array as `value, value` rather than `key, value` - I'm pretty sure that's how the route  parameter works in Laeavel: `Form::model('Model', ['route' => ['route.name', $model->getKey()]])` rather than your style of `Form::model('Model', ['route' => ['route.name' => $model->getKey()]])`

Comment: Oh thanks you put me to the right way, doesn't work first with replace ":" by "," but here is the right syntax for Twig:
form_model(edition,{'method' : 'PUT', 'route' : [ 'edition.update' , edition.id ], 'class' : 'form-horizontal',  'role' : 'form' })

Comment: I've posted this as the answer - feel free to accept or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to specify a route and its parameters in the `Form::open()` family of methods is as a non-keyed array - its first value is the route name, and the rest are the parameters to be sent.

You have (the equivalent of) this:

```
Form::model($edition, array(
    'method' => 'PUT',
    'class' => 'form-horizontal',
    'role' => 'form',
    'route' => array(
        'edition.update' => $edition->id,
    ),
));
```

But it needs to be like this:

```
Form::model($edition, array(
    'method' => 'PUT',
    'class' => 'form-horizontal',
    'role' => 'form',
    'route' => array(
        'edition.update',
        $edition->id,
    ),
));
```

As such, your twig needs to be:

```
{{ form_model(edition, {
    'method': 'PUT',
    'class': 'form-horizontal',
    'role': 'form',
    'route': ['edition.update', edition.id]
})|raw }}
```